# Accessing data from two or more schemas in a multi tenant application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

We are using [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) for multi-tenant application. For each account, there will be a separate schema is maintained. based on the subdomain of the account, we list the data in each account.

In our new requirement, there is something like a super account where all the account data can be viewed. For example, if account 1 and account 2 is selected in the user list page, users of account 1 and 2 should be combined and viewed along with search provision. Is there any way to combine more than one schema data in the apartment? or any other alternates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of is to perform union queries across the relevant schemas. So if you have schemas `account_1` and `account_2`, you'd do something like `SELECT * FROM account_1.users UNION SELECT * FROM account_2.users`.

You can, of course, make this dynamic – so if you send the affected accounts as part of the `params` hash, you'd potentially have something like this:

```rb
accounts = Account.find(params[:account_ids])
# assuming the schema name is stored in the accounts.tenant_name column:
sql = accounts.map { |account| "SELECT * FROM #{account.tenant_name}.users" }.join(" UNION ")
users = User.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is working. But is there any option in apartment gem to achieve this?

Comment: And how can we differentiate records based on accounts? - use case: I may need to show the info of the user account

Comment: Why would you want something "in the apartment gem" to achieve this? It's plain and simple default Rails with no additional gems, monkeypatching or anything. You _could_ rewrite it in Arel if that suits your taste better but again: I don't see any reason to do this.

Comment: As for your second question, I don't fully understand it. If what you're worried about here is permissions (i.e. not all users should be able to see all accounts), you can do something like this: `account_ids = params[:account_ids].map(&:to_i) & current_user.account_ids` (assuming `current_user.account_ids` includes all accounts the `current_user` has access to). This prevents exploits where a user tries to access resources they don't have access to. (Note: You can use a gem like cancancan or pundit if you want to go more in depth with permission management.)